# Is there any documentation on ServiceNow's Mobile app grouped list "Item View" JSON format/schema

Tags: mobile, servicenow

I'm creating a grouped list screen in ServiceNow's mobile app. I see that the Item View field is JSON that defines the layout options but I can't find ANY documentation on the format/schema or the JSON. They give [examples](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/madrid-mobile/page/administer/tablet-mobile-ui/task/sg-config-grouped-list.html) that contain a few of the options but nothing that tells you all of the various parameters that you can use.

```
{
      "Type": "ViewGroup",
      "Orientation": "Vertical",
      "Alignment": "Left",
      "Distribution": "Auto",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Type": "Text",
          "Text": "PLACEHOLDER",
          "CellId": "sys_group_by",
          "TextColor": "#293e40",
          "TextAlignment": "Left",
          "MaxLines": 2,
          "Font": {
            "Weight": "regular",
            "Size": 16
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Has anyone found a reference for the entire JSON schema of the Item View?